# How to import data using sqoop with ¡ (inverted exclamation mark) as delimiter

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to import data to HDFS (external location of hive) from Oracle using the following delimiter specifying 241 as the octal code but all the data is being imported to a single column of hive external table.

DELIMITER USED:

`¡` inverted exclamation mark

Code:

**Hive table**

```
Create External table table1(
  Column1 string,
  Column2 string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘-95’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
STORED AS TEXTFILE
Location "/user/hivepath";
```

**Sqoop import**

```
vchar=`printf "\241\n"`

sqoop import  \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdb \
--username root --password xxx \
--table table1 \
--fields-terminated-by $vchar \
--m 1 \
--target-dir /user/hivepath
```

I have to use the same DELIMITER as my hive table is constructed with the same one. Could you please provide me any alternate solution.

PS: I have tried with `|` as DELIMITER everything worked fine but I wanted to use inverted exclamation mark as the DELIMITER only.

Comment: How do the relevant parts of your sqoop command and hive DDL look like ?

Comment: Relevant parts in the sense? If you want me to use a different delimiter, I can load the data with that but my intention is to do it with this DELIMITER.

Comment: I mean, how does your sqoop command and hive create table statements look like? It's difficult to understand what's going wrong without looking at the code. Have a read [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: Edited the question and added the required code. Kindly keep me posted any alternate solution

Comment: Shouldn't it be `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\241'` instead of `-95` ?

Comment: Nope.. it doesn't work and one more thing there is no problem with hive DELIMITER as I loaded a file to hive path with same DELIMITER using FTP which worked..